# Is possible to display an error 500 with custom message laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, http

I am trying to display an error 500 with custom message in laravel 6.

Here's what I tried.

Controller `abort("500", $this->isAllSettingsSet() );`

View `@section('message', __($exception->getMessage()) ? __($exception->getMessage()) : __('Server Error'))` (Of course there's yield statement in layout file)

I searched about displaying 500 with custom message but, they all recommended using `abort` function with custom message in second parameter.
But it didn't work. just displaying "Server Error".

Thanks.

Comment: I found an article that I have to make a global variable and use that to store my message, but I think it's not a proper way to do. I need something that is not using global variable. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, take a look at the offical Error Handling documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors)

What you may want to do is throw a custom `Exception` like so:

```
throw new myCustomException('My Message');
```

This article may be of some use to you https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-catch-handle-create-laravel-exceptions/

Comment: Thanks. actually, $this->isAllSettingsSet() this function was always returning false. After fixing that, it works as intended.